# Not committing an hibernate entity field to the DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a basic hibernate entity which contains a few fields.
Currently all the fields are annotated with the @column annotation and the DB scheam corresponds accordingly.

Now, what I would like to do is to remove one of the fields from the DB but to keep it in the entity (it is only required for some validations, it should not be written to the DB).

So I have updated my DB scheam but what should I do with my entity?
Should I simply remove the @column annotation from the field or is there a spesific jpa annotation that exclude the field from the crud operations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Annotate the attribute in your entity class as *@Transient* and remove the *@Column* annotation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I think that annotating with @Transient will also prevent this field from being passed over the network (from the server to the client and back) since it will not be processed by jaxb (am I right?). This behaviour is not suitable for me since I would like to be able to pass this field from the client to the server but simply not to write it to the DB.

Comment: I don't know of any way to achieve this. You want to serialize the field using JAXB and you want to not serialize the field using JPA. Looks like an antagonism to me.

Maybe its better to use a separate transfer object for the JAXB part of your application. I think this will decouple your code a little bit more and make it better to maintain an to test it.

Comment: Hi, your definition of the problem is right on the spot. Your suggestion is one of the options, which I actually implemented for the moment (I wrapped my entity with a dto pojo and excluded my field from the entity to the pojo wrapper). Just thought maybe I'm missing something here, guess not. Thank you.