# Hibernate: Avoid persisting field during merge()

Tags: java, hibernate, blob, dozer

I have a webapp where users can upload files (via `multipart/form-data`), and they get stored along with their metadata in a DB with Hibernate (`@Entity class Document`).

The target table has a BLOB column `content` where the contents of the files are saved. Users who upload files are then allowed to modify some of the metadata (e.g. the original file name) in a GWT-based UI. To that end, I use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net) to convert `Document` instance into a `ClientDocument` instance, which does not have the `content` field and is serializable for GWT. Once a modified `ClientDocument` instance arrives from the browser, I convert it back into `Document` and execute this:

```
ClientDocument document = ...;
Document entity = dozerBeanMapper.map(document, Document.class);
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.merge(entity);
```

At this point the `entity`'s `content` column gets cleared, since Dozer, obviously, did not fill in the corresponding BLOB data.

Is there any way to avoid updating this particular BLOB `content` column during `merge()`? I have seen [Not committing an hibernate entity field to the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858526/not-committing-an-hibernate-entity-field-to-the-db), but the `@Transient` solution does not work for me, since I need to fetch the `content` BLOB for other operations in the backend.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Hibernate not to update the field at all

```
<property name="fieldName" insert="true" update="false"/>
```

Using annotations it will be something like this:

```
@Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)
```

Note, that the field is insertable which means it will be inserted, but next time you're going to update the entity, it won't be updated.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I need, since these blobs should be immutable (another document content is another row in the table.)